# Qt Designer - Generate only one .ui file with several widgets

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qt-designer

I started using Qt Designer a few weeks ago to generate some custom widgets for my PySide application. There is something I wish I could do, but I cannot manage to find how: I would like to save all my widgets in only one big `.ui`, then compile them to only one big `.py` file so that all the GUI details are in the same file, say `gui.py`. That would allow me to write things like this:

```
import gui.MainWindow
import gui.FluffyRabbitWidget

class MainWindow(gui.MainWindow): pass
class FluffyRabbitWidget(gui.FluffyRabbitWidget): pass
```

Then I would not have to bother having a whole bunch of different files with Python code that I will never read since it is generated. So, how could I manage to have just one big `.ui` file? And if not feasable, would there be a way to tell `pyside-uic` to generate only one `.py` file with several `.ui` files as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the source code of [`pyside-uic`](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-tools/blobs/cea64df8aedfdb2c8d8fe60bc329e6d15080e14d/pyside-uic), you can see that it doesn't accept more than one `.ui` argument:

```
opts, args = parser.parse_args()

if len(args) != 1:

    sys.stderr.write("Error: one input ui-file must be specified\n")

    sys.exit(1)

sys.exit(invoke(Driver(opts, args[0])))
```

So the answer is: no. `pyside-uic` can't do this.

A dirty solution *might* be to `cat` the generated files together, but this must be done every time you modify the widgets:

```
$ cat generated_*.py > gui.py
```

(Where `generated_*.py` should be a regex that matches the files generated for your widgets.

Comment: Ok, so no help from `pyside-uic`. I already thought of other dirty solutions; that one does not seem uglier than the others. Do you know whether there could be something feasable from Qt Designer? Reading the `.ui` XML, I can't whether several widgets can be put in only one `.ui` file.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not fond of XML schemas, so I don't understand whether multiple definitions on a single file are possible, but you may find the file format specification [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-ui-file-format.html).

Comment: @rlacko That seems a sensible solution, even though there are some drawbacks. For example you have to do `from gui.module_name import ClassName` instead of `from gui import ClassName`, but this can be fixed doing the imports inside the package `__init__.py`.

Comment: Since there don't semm to be a solution, I think that I will just put all the files in a subpackage and mess a little bit with `__all__` then.